Extraer un texto antes de una palabra en pandas python
En pandas ya pude extraer lo que esta despues de una palabra en un directorio con un pedaso de codigo que encontre por ahi, pero ahora quiero extraer lo que esta antes de la palabra.
import pandas as pd
d = {r'Descripción':['IPHONE 14 PRO MAX????\nApple: Apple iPhone 14 Pro MAX 128 GB Color Oro \n??Precio Oferta: $13,811.15\n']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df['Apple'] = df['Descripción'].str.extract(r'\n(Apple.*)\n')
print(df['Apple'])

Este es el codigo que tengo para extraer lo que esta despues de la palabra. ¿Como lo puedo modificar para que me de lo que esta antes de?

Simplemente "invierte el orden" de la regex:
df['Descripción'].str.extract(r'(.*)\nApple')

La salida sería:

0    IPHONE 14 PRO MAX????
Name: Apple, dtype: object


La expresión en si es simple:

(.*) -> Grupo de captura

. -> Coincide con cualquier carácter (excepto finales de línea)

* -> coincide con el token anterior entre cero y un número ilimitado de veces (codicioso)



\nApple -> Coincide con el literal (distinguiendo mayúsculas de minúsculas).


Si se diera el caso de querer incluir también los finales de con ., agrega la bandera re.DOTALL.
Si vas a partir el texto en dos usando el separador y cada parte va a una columna, quizás pandas.Series.str.split te convendría más, algo como:
df[['Usuario', 'Apple']] = df['Descripción'].str.split("\nApple: ", n=1, expand=True)

